# ValidationMessageFor mvc working only with decimal

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, validation

I have a ASP.NET MVC 4 project with EF and I have a validation problem in a view with some of my fields. 
I have noticed that the ValidationMessageFor works only for my decimal fields

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"></script>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Order", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.Label("Adresa livrare")
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.adresa, new { maxlength = "80" }) @*string - nvarchar*@
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.adresa)
</div>
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.Label("Curs Euro")
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.curs_euro, new { onkeypress = "return numericOnly(this)", id = "euro", maxlength = 9 }) @*decimal - decimal(10,2)*@
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.curs_euro, Resources.Global.strCursEuroV)
</div>
```

**Q:** Why is the validation is not working for the string fields ?

I've tried to decorate my model designer and add a [Required] but it messed up all my project.

```
[EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=false)]
[DataMemberAttribute()]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "validation messeage...")]
public global::System.String adresa
```

HTML

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        <label for="Adresa_livrare">Adresa livrare</label>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <input id="adresa" maxlength="80" name="adresa" type="text" value="" />
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="adresa" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        <label for="Curs_Euro">Curs Euro</label>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field curs_euro must be a number." data-val-required="The curs_euro field is required." id="euro" maxlength="9" name="curs_euro" onkeypress="return numericOnly(this)" type="text" value="" />
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="curs_euro" data-valmsg-replace="false">Introduceti cursul Euro</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Do you have

<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
</appSettings>

in your web config?

Comment: Yes, I have them. The validation works for my decimal field.

Comment: are you  trying to decorate with attributes code generated by designer?

Comment: I only want to validate in my view.

Comment: what does the generated html look like?

Comment: Can you be more specific on what "not working" means? Are they not working when you click on the TextBoxes and leave them after? Are they not working when you submit the form? thake a look at [this article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-validation-to-the-model), on the "Validation Error UI in ASP.NET MVC" section for an explanation on how "Required" works on Strings.

Comment: There is a difference between the string input and the decimal input...

Answer (score 1):

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.Label("Adresa livrare")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.adresa, new { minlength = 1, maxlength = 80 })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.adresa, "Adresa de livrare este    obligatorie")
    </div>//You need to set a minimum number of characters
```